# How do I change the value in an Excel table cell without specifying a cell reference in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

For example, in the following code, I look up a value from a table, increment the value, the write the new value back to the table. Right now, the value is written back to the table based on the cell name (i.e. "b5"). This all falls apart if the user sorts the table or adds/deletes and rows above it.
What I would like to do is determine the name of the cell that the value was loaded from at the time of the lookup so that the new value can be put back in the same place.

```
 '*** Lookup last DEWR number from Properties Page ***
    intDEWRNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
    "Current DEWR", Worksheets("Properties").ListObjects("propertiesTable").Range, 2, False)

    If intDEWRNum < 1 Then
        intDEWRNum = 1      ' If DEWR field is blank then this is the first DEWR.
    Else
        intDEWRNum = intDEWRNum + 1 ' Increment DEWR field
    End If

    Worksheets("Properties").Range("b5").Value = intDEWRNum
                               '^ This is what I want to avoid.***********


    newSheet.Name = "DEWR " & Str(intDEWRNum)   ' Name new worksheet with new DEWR number

    ActiveSheet.Range("j6").Value = Str(intDEWRNum)   ' Insert current DEWR number into sheet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim f as Range

Set f = Worksheets("Properties").ListObjects("propertiesTable"). _
        Range.Columns(1).Find("Current DEWR",lookin:=xlvalues, lookat:=xlwhole)

If not f is nothing then
    intDEWRNum = f.offset(0,1).Value

    If intDEWRNum < 1 Then
        intDEWRNum = 1      ' If DEWR field is blank then this is the first DEWR.
    Else
        intDEWRNum = intDEWRNum + 1 ' Increment DEWR field
    End If

    f.offset(0,1).Value= intDEWRNum

    'etc....
```